# Map of maps in Cassandra without using custom codec. Possible?

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm storing a Map containing Maps in a Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE reportsdb.report (
    report_id TEXT,
    entity_type TEXT,
    entity_id TEXT,
    parameters MAP<TEXT, FROZEN<MAP<TEXT, INT>>>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((report_id), entity_type, entity_id)
);
```

Storing data works fine without any issues.
When retreiving the data (using Java and datastax driver) I would like to do something like this:

```
resultSet.forEach(row -> {
        Map<String, Map> parametersMap = row.getMap("parameters", String.class, Map.class);
// Do something with the parametersMap here...
}
```

Since I cannot get the class of a generic type I need to define

```
Map<String, Map>
```

and cast that, when I would really would like to define

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>
```

However, when running the above code, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [map<varchar, int> <-> java.util.Map]
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:741)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:594)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:558)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.maybeCreateCodec(CodecRegistry.java:643)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:586)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.access$500(CodecRegistry.java:137)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:246)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:232)
wildfly       |     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542)
wildfly       |     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2323)
wildfly       |     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2286)
wildfly       |     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
wildfly       |     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
wildfly       |     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3957)
wildfly       |     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4875)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.lookupCodec(CodecRegistry.java:522)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:485)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.codecFor(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:73)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.getMap(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:338)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getMap(AbstractGettableData.java:26)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.getMap(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:327)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getMap(AbstractGettableData.java:26)
wildfly       |     at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getMap(AbstractGettableData.java:231)
wildfly       |     at com.ericsson.sm.reports.slaReport.SlaReportDao.lambda$getReportsFromResultSet$2(SlaReportDao.java:111)
wildfly       |     at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
wildfly       |     at com.ericsson.sm.reports.slaReport.SlaReportDao.getReportsFromResultSet(SlaReportDao.java:105)
wildfly       |     at com.ericsson.sm.reports.common.AbstractDao.getReports(AbstractDao.java:38)
wildfly       |     at com.ericsson.sm.reports.common.AbstractService.getReports(AbstractService.java:65)
wildfly       |     at com.ericsson.sm.reports.slaReport.SlaReportRestService.getDeviceSlaReports(SlaReportRestService.java:49)
wildfly       |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
wildfly       |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
wildfly       |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
wildfly       |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
wildfly       |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
wildfly       |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
wildfly       |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
wildfly       |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
wildfly       |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406)
wildfly       |     ... 56 more
```

It seems a bit strange to have to implement a custom codec because of the above.

Am I missing something obvious here? What would be the cleanest solution?

Thanks

Comment: considered `blob` and protocol buffers or something?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the issue by using type tokens instead:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> parametersMap = row
                .getMap("parameters", TypeToken.of(String.class), TypeTokens.mapOf(String.class, Integer.class));
```